# SQL Query to determine % of users in a cohort sent 1 or more invitations

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
USERS: id, created_at, onboarding_started_at
INVITATIONS: id, user_id
```

I'm working to write a query that shows the % of new users who sent 1 or more invites. Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT floor(datediff(u.created_at, curdate()) / 7) AS weeks_ago,
       count(DISTINCT u.id) AS "New Users in Cohort", 
       count(DISTINCT i.id) AS "Total Invites in Cohort",
       count(DISTINCT i.user_id) AS "Uniq Users who invited Cohort",
count(DISTINCT u.id) / count(DISTINCT i.user_id) AS "% who invite"
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN invitations i
     ON u.id = i.user_id
WHERE u.onboarding_started_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY weeks_ago;
```

Currently this is outputting, "% who invite" incorrectly. Example data:

```
weeks_ago | New Users in Cohort | Uniq Users who Invited Cohort | % who invite
-32 | 12 |  557 |  12 1.0000
```

In the above example, `% who invite` is showing 1.0000

What should I do to fix "% who invite" ?
Am I computing `Uniq Users who invited Cohort` incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: One or more invites during the week?  Or ever?

Comment: during the week/cohort...

Comment: Obviously, new users are associated with an invitation in your data set.

Comment: @GordonLinoff not following your comment...

Comment: . . All users have an associated invitation at some point in time.

Comment: hmm not all users send invites, so that's not the case...

Comment: . . According to your results all users that meet the condition `onboarding_started_at is not null` have an associated invitation.  That is from the `count()`s not the ratio -- the division seems fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried casting the values as DECIMAL?

CAST(count(DISTINCT u.id) AS DECIMAL(7,2)) / CAST(count(DISTINCT i.user_id) AS DECIMAL(7,2))